Managing the layering for Web View in my Cocos 2d App
I've created a scene in Cocos 2dx. It has multiple nodes. I've a WebView in one of the nodes. I'm using this WebView for loading a external website in my app. But the issue I'm facing is that the WebView always gets rendered at the top, it completely ignores the hierarchy between the nodes. Is there a way to fix this layering?
I've tried using SubContextView on the node in which WebView is added. But it has absolutely no effect on the current issue.
